# Is it possible for a HTTPPOST to be accessed via URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

For example, let's say that only User X can create Object Y.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  if(User != X)
   { 
      end;
   }
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SampleModel Y)
{
  AddtoDB(X);
}
```

Is it possible for the URL to be occupied such that is goes directly to the HttpPost thereby bypass the authentication? Something like localhost123:Controller/Action/?

Comment: Yes. You can easily send a POST request using any HTTP tool (like cURL)

Comment: So authentication checks must be placed in POST as well?

Comment: Yes. It's been a while since I did any .NET MVC but isn't there an annotation for secured / authenticated controller actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can post directly without going through `HTTPGet` first. Instead of doing authentication checks in the action itself, decorate your action with the authorize attribute and provide the roles parameter

```
[Authorize(Roles="CanCreate"]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ...
}
```

Sometimes you need more fine grain control over who to let into the action, such as the case where users can on create items for certain departments. In that case you may write a custom authorize attribute or simply write it into the action.